# how to grab specific json nested values in powershell?

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have this command here:

```
(Get-Content output.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

that pulls json file and puts all the top levels into a csv format. however, i want some nested values inside there as well. I know there is a command -depth that wlil pull all values at a certain depth, but I only wnat to specify a certain one. For example, if I want to pull /data/1/structure/name, how would I get that value specifically as well?

Comment: This might be easier if you include some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Select-object:

```
(Get-Content output.json -Raw |Select value1,Valu2,Valu | ConvertFrom-Json) | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: do the values go in quotes? or how are they written out ? for exmaple pulling data/1/whatever, how would you put that in for value ?

Comment: can you post the result of (Get-Content output.json -Raw |Select value1,Valu2,Valu" | ConvertFrom-Json)